# Nodejs package.json defining scripts with the same name as a dependency

Tags: json, node.js

I've seen a lot of `package.json` files where there are scripts that doesn't do anything but call a dependency with the same name. For example :

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
        "tslint": "tslint"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "tslint": "~4.4.2",
        "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0"
    }
}
```

Here we have the script `tslint` that just calls the dependency `tslint`. I guess that is some kind of a way to make the `lint` script shorter but how would it look like if there was no script called `tslint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe NPM has this kind of functionality built in. [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com) (the third-party NPM client built by Facebook, Google, Exponent and Tilde) on the other hand, does - you can just use `yarn run` and it will pick up the executable from your dependencies, even if you don't have a script for it defined in your `package.json`:

```
yarn run tslint
yarn run tslint "src/**/*.ts"
```

Comment: So basically in order to use the dependency you have to have a script with the same name?

Comment: @chnging: That, or install the tool as a global dependency (`npm install -g tslint`) too, so you can just run it like `tslint`. Most Node command line tools check the current directory for a locally installed version and defer to that if it's there.

Comment: @chnging: As an example: if you have Webpack 2.0.0 installed globally on your computer, and your `package.json` depends on Webpack 2.0.1 (or something like that), running `webpack` from the command line will use the locally installed 2.0.1 version. I can't say for sure if tslint does the same, but a lot of tools do!